# How to upload a file created in java without using Input file in HTML5

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, html, wcf

I everyone, I want to know how to upload a File in HTML5, without Input file, or at least without clicking on it. If there is a way to put it in without clicks and searching fo it, I would like to hear about it.

The thing is, in HTML5 I have a table, when is clicked it opens a modal with info, that info is sent by AJAX to a .jsp file, where I create a PDF using the info, in a certain path. I want to use the same file to upload it with a WCF service, but all what I could do was to create it, and then to look for it with an input file, but I want to use it with out the input file.

Here is some of my code...

**The JSP File where I create the PDF file:**

```
<%
String idP = request.getParameter("idP");
String nombreP = request.getParameter("NombreP");
String nombreC = request.getParameter("NombreC");
String presupuesto = request.getParameter("Presupuesto");
String avance = request.getParameter("Avacne");
String empleado = request.getParameter("Empleado");
String constructora = request.getParameter("Constructora");
String idC = request.getParameter("idC");
String idE = request.getParameter("idE");
String idT = request.getParameter("idT");

Font GreenFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD, new CMYKColor(0, 0, 255, 0));
Font yellowFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD, new CMYKColor(255, 0, 255, 0));
String path = "E:" + File.separator + "Reportes" + File.separator + "Reporte " + nombreP + ".pdf";
Document document = new Document();
File file = new File(path);
try {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file.getPath()));
    document.open();

    Paragraph chapterTitle = new Paragraph(nombreP, yellowFont);
    Chapter chapter1 = new Chapter(chapterTitle, 1);
    chapter1.setNumberDepth(0);
    document.add(chapter1);

    document.add(new Paragraph("Nombre cliente:" + nombreC));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Presupuesto: $" + presupuesto));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Avance del proyecto: %" + avance));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Nombre del empleado: " + empleado));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Constructora: " + constructora));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Id_Proyecto: " + idP));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Id_Constructora: " + idC));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Id_Empleado: " + idE));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Id_Tipo: " + idT));

    document.addAuthor("Erick Adahir");
    document.addCreationDate();
    document.addCreator("LorCyC");
    document.addTitle("AVAVAGO");
    document.addSubject("Un simple ejemplo");

    document.close();
    writer.close();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

**The function that calls the JSP:**

```
function agregarEventoDoubleClickEnTablaProyecto()
{
$('#tablaProyecto td').dblclick(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    var row = $this.closest("tr"); //Hacemos referencia al registro padre de la celda
    //alert(row.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    //row.find('td:firs').text();

    alert("PDF");
    $.ajax({
        url: "Proyecto/creaPDF.jsp",            
        data: {                
            idP: id,
            NombreP: row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            NombreC: row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            Presupuesto: row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
            Avance: row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
            Tipo: row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
            Empleado: row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
            Constructora: row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
            idC: row.find('td:eq(8)').text(),
            idE: row.find('td:eq(9)').text(),
            idT: row.find('td:eq(10)').text()
        }            
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("nice...");
    });
    $('#areaDatosProyecto').modal({
        show: 'true'
    });
});
}
```

**And finally, the function that uploads the File using Input File:**

```
function subir() {
            var archivo = document.getElementById("btnFile").files[0];
            alert(archivo);
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () {
                var bString = this.result;                 
                var objUp = {
                    elemento: {
                        NombreOriginal: "nombre",
                        Documento: bString.split("base64,")[1]
                    }
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:84/Uploader/ServicioUploader.svc/ArchivarDocumento",
                    data: JSON.stringify(objUp),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var id = data.d;
                        alert(id);
                    },
                    error: function (xnr, status, error) {
                        alert("XNR: " + xnr + ", STATUS: " + status + ", ERROR: " + error);
                    }
                });
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(archivo);
        }
```

Hope someone can lend me a hand! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the file inside a JSP. 
Which means that it should be created  on the path ***(E:/Reportes/Reporte/[your filename].pdf)*** where your server is hosted.

You can write the code for upload right there in your JSP itself (where the file object is being created).

I dont see a point of two AJAX calls.

Comment: But I thought there was no way to call a WCF in Java, I think I understand what you say, But what I want to know is how to send the file object?

Comment: Oh. I get the point. Stil, it might be tricky because the file is created on the server (from the JSP), and your javascript's CLIENT would be the USER, you will not be able to do this via client side scripting.
1) Client side script would find the path on the client machine (and the file is created on server) and hence the file will not be found.
2) If somehow you made this possible, you cannot access a physical file on client machine via jQuery/Javascript because of seurity issues.
You'll have to find a way to do this the "backend-only" way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do, but If I am understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like you are creating this PDF "server side" on your own system, and saving it to disk, and then on the same system loading up a "client side" web app where you have an upload control (i.e. file selector) where the user selects the PDF that is then uploaded to another server, but you are trying to avoid needing the user to manually select the file to upload in the final step.

If this is your case, unfortunately you cannot do that because it is a security risk, any modern browser will not allow you to programmatically upload a file from a user's hard drive without their manual selection of the file.

SO, not to try and be negative, but it sounds like you may be going about this the wrong way. Why don't you create AND upload the PDF from your server-side (JSP) code? It seems like adding in the client-side web app here is unnecessary. Since you already know WHERE to send the PDF (your URL looks hard-coded there) and you apparently control the server side code, it seems the simplest solution would be to just open an HTTPUrlConnection (or use whatever library you may like) to send the raw bytes of the PDF to it's final destination.

Comment: Agree. And also, the "FILE" object from the JSP is created on server, and the access is happening via front-end scripting (jQuery/javascript), the front-end script would try to find the file on the client, but actually it would be on the server. Therefore, "backend-only" approach is the way to go.